# Attach images to posts using custom fields (just paths to images already uploaded)

Tags: custom-field, attachments, xml

I'm setting up a real estate website. I make listings using a custom post type named `listings` in which I have multiples meta boxes for **beds**, **baths**, and various other information.

I use a plugin to import these posts because listings are generated from third-party software (XML file with Xpaths). Everything works fine when importing listings.

The BUT is that the theme inserts images **attached to the post** `_wp_attach_file` ... file.

The XML makes easy to get the paths to images, but I can't figured out how to make them 'be attached' to the post to load up.

Is it possible to attach them using custom fields?

(I need to do this for almost 500 posts through **WP ALL IMPORT - XML XPath** importer plugin - which I can insert `custom_fields` and meta boxes lines.)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend just modifying the `single-listings.php` template file to output the gallery directly:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[gallery] ); ?>
```

That way, for all the images that have been imported and attached to a given CPT, they weill be output just as if you had placed a `[gallery]` shortcode in the post_content for each post.

### Edit

If you have post metadata that contains image URL paths, and you want to upload/attach those images to the post, then have a look at [**`media_sideload_image()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image) (or, [in 3.5, **`wp_sideload_image()`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19629)).

Comment: I does that already, the problem is that there is no attached files the CPT. I'm trying to figure out how to attach them. I tried to set the path to the file with custom field for each post: _wp_attached_file -> DIR/uploads/2012/IMAGE.JPG and i doesn't work, any idea of what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, I was confused by the wording of the question. So you don't actually have images *attached* to the post, but rather you have *custom post metadata* for the images, with *meta keys* like `_wp_attach_file`?

Comment: I manually upldd images through ftp (16000 images), those imgs are the listings imgs (500 listings). The theme, only calls images when they are _attached_ to the CPT. I cant manage to add them manually (post by post), so I have to find a way to attach them when I do the import. Importing the listings I can set custom fields for each, using the XML to provide the path. I browsed up the db to see an example of an attached file looks like and it shows a meta_key and meta_value (key-> _wp_attached_file | value-> 2012/11/IMAGE.JPG). So I am trying to _attach_ it like that. but it isnt working.

Comment: I don't know if the meta_id or post_id has something to do with that, I really don't understand much about it. Is those path's case sensitive? (thanks for your attention)

Comment: How can i do this media_sideload?

Comment: Did you read the linked Codex entry?

Comment: I saw the media_sideload, but it isn't possible for the application i'm making. I need to make this trough CF, do you know if it's possible? i tried looking everywhere i couldnt find nothing

Comment: What do you mean, *"through CF"*?

Comment: Custom Field...

Comment: Essentially, post custom meta (i.e. custom fields) and post attachments (i.e. attached images) are mutually exclusive. The same content can be one or the other, but not both.

Comment: I'm so stupid. I didn't noticed there was a field saying: ATTACHMENTS on the import wizard... Solved A BIG THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Furtado figured out the answer and posted it as a comment buried under the original post. WP All Import has an option to import images as attachments:

> I didn't noticed there was a field saying: ATTACHMENTS on the import
>   wizard... Solved A BIG THANKS

Comment: Re-posted this answer from a comment for visibility.

Answer (score 0):

If your uploading the photos via ftp, WordPress won't know about them in the media library. If that's Ok with you then you take the image URLs from the XML being loaded, create a serialized array using `maybe_serialize()` and then save it as a custom field to the post.